# How to iterate a command (loop) through files in a list in Python

Tags: python

I'm new in Python. I'm trying to a write a brief script. I want to run a loop in which I have to read many files and for each file run a command.In particular, I want to do a calculation throught the the two rows of every file and return an output whith a name which is refered to the relative file.

I was able to load the files in a list ('work'). I tried to write the second single loop for the calculation that I have to do whith one of the file in the list and it runs correctly. THe problem is that I'm not able to iterate it over all the files and obtain each 'integr' value from the relative file.

Let me show what I tried to do:

```
import numpy as np

#I'm loading the files that contain the values whith which I want to do my calculation in a loop

work = {}
for i in range(0,100):
    work[i] = np.loadtxt('work{}.txt'.format(i), float).T

#Now I'm trying to write a double loop in which I want to iterate the second loop (the calculation) over the files (that don't have the same length) in the list

integr = 0

for k in work:
    for i in range(1, len(k[1,:])):
                  integr = integr + k[1,i]*(k[0,i] - k[0,i-1])

#I would like to print every 'integr' which come from the calculation over each file

print(integr)
```

When I try to run this, I obtain this message error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lavoro.py", line 11, in <module>
    for i in range(1, len(k[1,:])):
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `work = {}` creates an empty dictionary not a list, which would be `work = []`. Did you want a dictionary or a list?

Comment: Please post minimal, **working** example and more explanations, what do you want to achieve. Otherwise we will be guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit guessing, but if I understood correctly, you want `work` to be a *list* and not a *dictionary*. Or maybe you don't want it, but surely you can use a list instead of a dictionary, given the context.
This is how you can create your `work` list:

```
work = []
for i in range(0,100):
    work.append(np.loadtxt('work{}.txt'.format(i), float).T)
```

Or using the equivalent list comprehension of the above loop (usually the list comprehension is faster):

```
work = [np.loadtxt('work{}.txt'.format(i), float).T for i in range(100)]
```

Now you can loop over the `work` list to do your calculations (I assume they are correct, no way for me to check this):

```
for k in work:
    integr = 0
    for i in range(1, len(k[1,:])):
        integr = integr + k[1,i]*(k[0,i] - k[0,i-1])
```

Note that I moved `integr = 0` inside the loop, so that is reinitalized to 0 for each file, otherwise each inner loop will add to the result of the previous inner loops.
However if that was the desided behaviour, move `integr = 0` outside the loop as your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing from the context you wanted:

```
for k in work.values():
```

iterating over dictionary produces only keys, not values.

Comment: The first line belongs to a comment instead of an answer IMO